# Using case statement within a crosstab function

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to use a case statement within a "crosstab" function? This is what I have put together thus far.

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab('select distinct test_id,  cluster,total_points_earned FROM pmt_cluster')
case when test_id = 451 end AS Algebra( 
      "School___Teacher" text,
     "Analyze functions using different representations" text,
     "Construct and compare linear, quadratic, and exponential models and solve problems" text,
     "Create equations that describe numbers or relationships" text,
     "Expressions and Equations" text)
case when test_id = 454 end AS Ela( 
     "School___Teacher" text,
     "Key Ideas and Details" text,
     "Conventions of Standard English" text,
     "Craft and Structure" text,
     "Vocabulary Acquisition and Use" text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need this to call it from psql. Because it is no problem to create expected SQL statement in any external languages.

To do it you can use \gset command. It sends the current query input buffer to the server and stores the query's output into psql variable. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

```
SELECT 451 AS test_id;
\gset


SELECT CASE WHEN :test_id = 451 THEN 'Algebra' WHEN :test_id = 454 THEN 'Ela' END AS ttype,
        '"School___Teacher"' AS f1, 'text' AS t1,
        'text' AS tX,
        CASE WHEN :test_id = 451 THEN '"Analyze functions using different representations"' WHEN :test_id = 454 THEN '"Key Ideas and Details"' END AS f2,
        CASE WHEN :test_id = 451 THEN '"Construct and compare linear, quadratic, and exponential models and solve problems"' WHEN :test_id = 454 THEN '"Conventions of Standard English"' END AS f3,
        CASE WHEN :test_id = 451 THEN '"Create equations that describe numbers or relationships"' WHEN :test_id = 454 THEN '"Craft and Structure"' END AS f4,
        CASE WHEN :test_id = 451 THEN '"Expressions and Equations"' WHEN :test_id = 454 THEN '"Vocabulary Acquisition and Use"'  END AS f5;
\gset

SELECT * 
      FROM crosstab('select distinct test_id,  cluster,total_points_earned FROM pmt_cluster')
        AS :ttype(:f1 :t1, :f2 :tX, :f3 :tX, :f4 :tX, :f5 :tX);
;
```

Comment: getting the following error: Error: You do not have permission to run GSET queries. I think it will work if i can get pass this permission error.

Comment: it's for the first gset.

Comment: you run it from psql?

Comment: Can you try it from postgres user? And which version of postgresql do you use?

Comment: We  have two platforms: test and production. When i run on production, I get don't  have permission error. However, when i run it from test, i get the following error: Error: SQL Error: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 2: \gset ^ Query: \gset SELECT CASE WHEN :test_id = 451 THEN 'Algebra' WHEN :test_id = 454 THEN 'Ela' END AS ttype, '"School___Teacher"' AS f1, 'text' AS t1, 'text' AS tX, CASE WHEN :test_id = 451 THEN '"Analyze functions using different representations"' WHEN :test_id = 454 THEN '"Key Ideas and Details"' END AS f2,.....

Comment: version PostgreSQL 9.4.8

Comment: Could you try to run two command. First (in line 1) `SELECT 1 AS id; \gset` + enter. And at the next line:" `SELECT :id;` + enter

Comment: Error: SQL Error: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: \gset + enter ^ Query: \gset + enter SELECT :id Error Info: Array ( [0] => 42601 [1] => 7 [2] => ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: \gset + enter ^ )
+ enter
Error: SQL Error: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "+" LINE 1: + enter ^ Query: + enter Error Info: Array ( [0] => 42601 [1] => 7 [2] => ERROR: syntax error at or near "+" LINE 1: + enter ^ )

Comment: First line "SELECT 1 AS id; \gset"

Comment: SELECT 1 AS id; \gset

Comment: Result must be  :  id1 
-----
   1
(1 row)

Comment: Next line to run :

Comment: Error: SQL Error: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: \gset ^ Query: \gset Error Info: Array ( [0] => 42601 [1] => 7 [2] => ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: \gset ^ )

Comment: SELECT :id as id;

Comment: I did get the result id1 ----- 1 (1 row), but followed the error message

Comment: do you run this comment from `psql` ? Or from pgadmin?

Comment: I don't have permission to run gset function. therefore, i have taken a different approach by declaring my variable with a "CTE".  However, I am unable to change the table headings based on declared id. Please see complete code. You can skip to bottom to crosstab function.  Here's the link [link](http://confapp.martinschools.org/crosstab.html